# Jest mockImplementationOnce is not overriding existing mock

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a common mock module as below:

```
// File: /<rootDir>/utils/__mocks__/mock-foo.js

const foo = require('foo');
jest.mock('foo');

foo.myFunction = jest.fn(() => ({
   value: 10
  }
));
```

In the `jest.config.js` I have below line, to make above mock available in all tests.

```
const config = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/utils/__mocks__/mock-foo.js'
  ]
}
```

Below is the unit test for `myFlow.js` file which is using `Foo.js`.

```
File: /<rootDir>/__test__/myFlow.js

const myFlow = require('../myFlow');
const foo = require('../foo');

describe('my unit tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('test my function', async () => {

    // This is not working, I always get value as 10    
    foo.myFunction.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      value: 20,
    }));

    const result = await myFlow.someFunction();
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

How can I override the existing mock with jest `mockImplementationOnce`?